# dotnet-trace does not resolve symbols under linux-arm

Tags: c#, .net-core, arm, embedded-linux, trace

I want to use `dotnet-trace` on `linux-arm` to analyse my application, but the symbols/names of my application are not resolved for some reason.

If I use `dotnet-trace` for the same application on `linux-x64` it will resolve the symbols/names just fine.

An example trace on `linux-arm` looks like this in `PerfView`:

[Trace on linux-arm in PerfView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6rwG.png)

Here are my detailed steps. My application `TestTrace` consists of 2 files:

Program.cs:

```
using System;

namespace TraceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DoSomething ...");
            DoSomething();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
        }

        static void DoSomething()
        {
            for(var i = 0; i< 1_000_000_000; i++){}
        }
    }
}
```

TraceTest.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

1. How I build the binaries for `linux-arm` on Windows:

```
dotnet publish --configuration Debug -r linux-arm --self-contained
```

2. I copied the whole content inside the directory `..\TraceTest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp5.0\linux-arm\publish` to `$HOME/TraceTest` on `linux-arm`
3. Install the `.net core 5.0 sdk` on `linux-arm` (all the following commands were executed as `root`.):

```
wget https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/726e260e-ce94-46c3-a169-57b2ebf5433d/5fb2a00b04b3509a0a6db63e302523a8/dotnet-sdk-5.0.102-linux-arm.tar.gz -O dotnet-sdk-5.0.102-linux-arm.tar.gz
mkdir -p "$HOME/dotnet" && tar zxf dotnet-sdk-5.0.102-linux-arm.tar.gz -C "$HOME/dotnet"
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
```

4. Install `dotnet-trace` on `linux-arm`:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-trace
export PATH="$PATH:/home/root/.dotnet/tools"
```

5. Collect a trace for my `TraceTest` application:

```
cd $HOME/TraceTest
chmod +x TraceTest
dotnet-trace collect -- TraceTest
```

I got the following output (i stopped the trace manually here):

```
root@myLinuxArmMachine:$HOME/TraceTest# dotnet-trace collect -- TraceTest
No profile or providers specified, defaulting to trace profile 'cpu-sampling'

Provider Name                           Keywords            Level               Enabled By
Microsoft-DotNETCore-SampleProfiler     0x0000F00000000000  Informational(4)    --profile
Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime         0x00000014C14FCCBD  Informational(4)    --profile

Process        : $HOME/TraceTest/TraceTest
Output File    : $HOME/TraceTest/trace.nettrace
[00:00:00:17]   Recording trace 599.055  (KB)
Press <Enter> or <Ctrl+C> to exit...969  (KB)
Stopping the trace. This may take up to minutes depending on the application being traced.

Trace completed.
```

6. I opened the trace file `$HOME/TraceTest/trace.nettrace` on my windows machine with `PerfView`. I double-clicked on `Thread Time (with StartStop Activities) Stacks` and opened the tab `CallTree`, but there were no resolved symbols/names (see the screenshot from above).

I did the same tracing process on `linux-x64` and the symbols/names were resolved just fine:
[Trace with symbols/names on linux-x64 in PerfView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvpjW.png)

Other things i tried without success:

- Use .net core 3.1 instead 5.0 (so adapt the TraceTest.csproj, use the .net core 3.1 sdk and install dotnet-trace for .net core 3.1). I know that it is not possible to do the `dotnet-trace collect -- TraceTest` command on `.net core 3.1` (so i added a Console.ReadKey() to my Program.cs and started the application manually).
- Convert the trace to the speedscope format via `dotnet-trace convert trace.nettrace --format Speedscope --output trace.speedscope`. But you can clearly see, that there are no resolved names for any frames inside the trace.speedscope.json. In comparsion i can see some meaningful fames names in the converted trace of `linux-x64`.
- Copy the project `TestTrace` directly to `linux-arm` and execute it via `dotnet run`.
- Do not stop the tracing manually. I always get the following error, but i do not think this should affect the tracing result:

```
[ERROR] Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.ServerNotAvailableException: Could not send Stop command. The target process may have exited.
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.EventPipeSession.Stop() in /_/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client/DiagnosticsClient/EventPipeSession.cs:line 62
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tools.Trace.CollectCommandHandler.Collect(CancellationToken ct, IConsole console, Int32 processId, FileInfo output, UInt32 buffersize, String providers, String profile, TraceFileFormat format, TimeSpan duration, String clrevents, String clreventlevel, String name, String diagnosticPort) in /_/src/Tools/dotnet-trace/CommandLine/Commands/CollectCommand.cs:line 221
```

I also searched for related problems, but i cannot find my exact problem (working fine on `linux-x64`, but not on `linux-arm`).

I hope i missing out something simple here and someone can help me.